# How does a boost::archive::binary_oarchive handle an enum?

Tags: c++, boost, enums

I have the following Enum

```
enum Example : uint8_t {
   First = 1,
   Second = 2,
 };
```

and a stringstream:

```
std::stringstream stream;
boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(stream);
```

now i have noticed that, if i serialize an enum:

```
ar << Example::First;
```

boost serializes 4 byte (in this case 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)  bit instead of the needed 8 bit (0x01) for an uint8_t.
Is there any way to avoid this? I mean, I know I can cast that enum to an uint8_t but this seams not very smart (and I have to change a lot of things if I have to do this).

Thanks and Greetings

Comment: Enums with specific type backings is a new(ish) C++11 feature, and there's still significant portions of boost which were designed specifically for C++03.  It's _possible_ this is a case of `boost` not knowing about a "new" language feature, and boost needs an update.

Comment: I can't decide if this is a duplicate of [How to change the default enums serialization in Boost.Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635534/how-to-change-the-default-enums-serialization-in-boost-serialization) or not.

Comment: I found a bug where boost serialization fails with strongly-typed enums, and it was closed as "invalid".  Not sure if that means that there's no intention to support it or what.  https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6068

Comment: [This thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/serializing-enums-and-arrays-td2563202.html) suggests that it was designed with enum==int because there was an old (noncompliant) C++ compiler that treated enumerations as integers that they wanted to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always with Boost Serialization, to customize the treatment of user-defined types you'd need to implement the *customization point* which is either member `serialize/load/save` or free function `serialize/load/save` (looked up by ADL).

Since member functions are not an option for enums, you'd need to supply an overload of, e.g., `serialize` for your type. Sadly there is no way to get a generic implementation of that to be "better" than the predefined overloads for builtin primitive types.

Here's what would comes close (but it doesn't work ¹):

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

        template <typename Ar, typename T>
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, void>::type
            serialize(Ar& ar, T& e, unsigned) 
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::make_binary_object(&e, sizeof(e));
            }

} }
```

> We can take the shortcut of "binary_object" serialization as we know by definition that enums have integral values as their underlying type, which makes them POD.

In the light of this - unfortunate - limitation, perhaps the best way is to manually call `make_binary_object` as shown:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35b2888b69def34c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint8_t {
    First  = 1,
    Second = 2,
};

int main() {

    std::stringstream stream;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(stream, boost::archive::no_header);

    auto data = Example::First;
    ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));

    std::cout << "Size: " << stream.str().size() << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
Size: 1
```

as expected. You can use the `make_binary_object` wrapper inside `serialize` implementations and it will transparently take care of both serialization and deserialization.

See: [**Boost Serialization Wrappers**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#binaryobjects) in the Boost documentation

---

¹ for similar reasons, `BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(Example)` will not work; I tested it

Comment: Why binary serialization when you can do serialization through the integer (or underlying type)? (like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15d39b868058a490)

Comment: @alfC That should probably be equivalent. `make_binary_object` is more general, and applies to all POD types. (I misread your comment earlier, sorry)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem with binary serialization; it is too general. I would use binary serialization as a last resort. (see my answer).

Comment: Did you actually manage to make the customization of your code above (defined inside `boost::serialization` namespace) ? I tried it and it seems to be ignored or something has higher precedence. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32cfef6b34ebbc61

Comment: @alfC It literally says so in the answer text: _"Here's what would comes close (but it doesn't work ¹)"_

Comment: Yeah, maybe you managed after 2015 :). Anyway, it is very unfortunate that enum classes cannot be customized for serialization because one might want to have human-readable xml or text archinves, by serializing the names of the enums (e.g. <color>red</color>` instead of `<color>3</color>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the natural answer would be to convert the enum to the underlying type of the enum and (de)serialize that.

At the least, this will give a more readable output; and at the best, it will create more compatible archives across systems.

Also notice that `binary` serialization can break xml's (which I think it is a bug in Boost.Serialization)

```
using boost::serialization::make_binary_object;

enum class Example : uint8_t {
    First  = 1,
    Second = 2,
};

int main() {

    std::stringstream stream;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive ar(stream, boost::archive::no_header);

    auto data = Example::First;
    auto data_ul = static_cast<uint8_t>(data);

    ar << boost::make_nvp("data", data_ul);
    
    ar << boost::make_nvp("data_bin", make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data)));

    ar << make_binary_object(&data, sizeof(data));

    std::cout << "Size: " << stream.str() << "\n";
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c824a88d139d07cf

output:

```
Size: <data>1</data>

<data_bin>

AQ==

</data_bin>


AQ==
```

Comment: "At the least, this will give a more readable output" - the question is specifically about `binary_oarchive` though. I'd agree for the rest. +1

Comment: Do you have some more information on "_binary serialization can break xml's_"? I think I've seen problems in Boost Property Tree when serializing embedded NUL chars to the XML backend, but I don't immediately remember such issues with Boost Serialization `xml_oarchive` (though it has many flaws and traps)

Comment: @sehe, no additional information, I just found out about it (see the code output in my answer).

Comment: But that's just when you forget to add the NVP wrapper. I guess there's a QOI issue where the code only statically checks for "a wrapper type" (which the result of `make_binary_object` _also is_), instead of "nvp wrapper type" specifically.